# how to pass an argument from python code to bash script?

Tags: python, bash, arguments

I have a python code in which at the beginning it takes a string variable let say "element_name" from user and build some sub-folders based on this string and also some output files created by this code move to those folders.

On the other hand, I have a bash script in which some codes should be running in the sub-folders made in python code.

Any help how to introduce those folders in bash? How to pass the "element_name" from python to bash?

In python code "a.py" I tried

```
first = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/echo', element_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

second = subprocess.Popen(['bash', 'path/to/script', '--args'], stdin=first.stdout)
```

and then in bash

```
source a.py
echo $element_name
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question what is in your scripts, but I guess

```
subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', 'path/to/script', '--args', element_name])
```

is doing what you intend to do, passing the value of `element_name` to `script` as an argument.

Comment: Also, `source a.py` will attempt to run a.py as a shell script instead of python. If you want to print element_name to console you can do it inside a.py with a print() statement. If you want to capture this in the shell you can assign the output to a variable using `FOO=$(./a.py)`. However, make sure the script is executable first with `chmod +x a.py`

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. What I did is to pass the argument in a bash file and import this bash file as a source to my main bash file. Now everything works well.